# Struggling to understand a "Cannot construct the infinite type" error

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to solve a HackerRank problem and I am getting an error that I cannot figure out. The issue is in the `solve1` function. The exact error is: `` cannot construct the infinite type a ~ t0 a. Expected type ([t0 a], [t0 a], [t0 a]) Actual type ([a], [a], [a]). In the second argument of `tripleMap`, namely '(tripList xs)' ``.

I keep looking at the types and they continue to appear correct in my eyes. `tripList` takes a list of numbers and returns a triple of lists of numbers. `tripleMap` takes a triple of lists of numbers as its second argument.

In testing `tripList` in my REPL I get the desired results:

```
> tripList [1,0,-1,0,1] 
([1,1],[0,0],[-1])
```

Here is my code:

```
length' :: (Foldable t, Num b, Fractional b, Ord b) => t a -> b
length' = foldr (\_ acc -> 1 + acc) 0

tripList :: (Num a, Ord a) => [a] -> ([a], [a], [a])
tripList xs =
  ( filter (>0) xs
  , filter (==0) xs
  , filter (<0) xs )

foldSolution :: (Foldable t, Num a, Ord a, Fractional a)
             => a -> t a -> a
foldSolution n = foldr (\x y -> x/n + y/n) 0

tripleMap :: (a -> b) -> ([a], [a], [a]) -> ([b], [b], [b])
tripleMap f (a, b, c) = (map f a, map f b, map f c)

solve1 :: (Num a, Ord a) => [a] -> ([a], [a], [a])
solve1 xs = tripleMap (foldSolution (length' xs)) (tripList xs)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `foldSolution (length' xs)` takes `t a` and returns `a`. So, when you `tripleMap` it on `tripList xs` (which has type `([a], [a], [a])`), you get a tuple of type `(a, a, a)`, not `([a], [a], [a])`, which is why you got the error.